# cookies permission for chrome app

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-extension, permissions, google-chrome-app

I am trying to make a custom cookie manager app for chrome, but the "cookies" permission in the manifest.json file gets me this warning

```
'cookies' is only allowed for extensions and legacy packaged apps...`
```

My app can't be an extension instead because I also want access to "filesystem" and maybe "usb".

This is not the first time I need extension APIs for an app or vice versa. Is there any way to make an app that can use extension APIs or the other way round?

Answer (score 1):

You could develop an extension as a dependency for your app. It's not ideal since it requires the user to install two items but it should work. You can implement [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external) between your app and the extension to call the needed APIs.